# How to send an enum value in a notification in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, nsnotificationcenter

I want to send an enum as an object in a notification :

```
enum RuleError:String {
    case Create, Update, Delete
}

class myClass {

   func foo() {
       NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RuleFailNotification", 
                                            object: RuleError.Create)
   }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work since an enum **does not match** `AnyObject?`.

Any idea how to circumvent this problem ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `object` parameter in the function you're using is the sender, the object posting the notification, not the parameter. Check out the docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:userInfo:).

You should put the enum value you want to send as a parameter in the user info dictionary and use the following method:

```
func postNotificationName(_ aName: String,
                   object anObject: AnyObject?,
                 userInfo aUserInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]?)
```

In your case:

```
let userInfo = ["RuleError" : RuleError.Create.rawValue]

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RuleFailNotification",
        object: self,
        userInfo:userInfo)
```

And to handle the notification, first register for it:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
        self,
        selector: "handleRuleFailNotification:",
        name: "RuleFailNotification",
        object: nil)
```

Then handle it:

```
func handleRuleFailNotification(notification: NSNotification) {

        let userInfo = notification.userInfo

        RuleError(rawValue: userInfo!["RuleError"] as! String)
    }
```

Comment: This is an unfortunate necessity. Notifications force enums and structs into second class status. I feel this is a major shortcoming in Swift, since Enums are often just a restricted Int or String, and yet these are fine as a value.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution is to send the raw value

```
RuleError.Create.rawValue
```

which could be later converted back to an enum

```
RuleError(rawValue : "Create")
```

But the `object` parameter isn't the appropriate place to send custom data. Better use the `userInfo` dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

You can use boxing to send a pure Swift type like enum via NSNotification.

```
final class Box<T>: NSObject {
   let value: T
   init(_ value: T) {
      self.value = value
   }
}
```

To post a notification:

```
let userInfo = ["RuleError" : Box(RuleError.Create)]
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("RuleFailNotification",
    object: self,
    userInfo:userInfo)
```

In your observer, the value can be retrieved as:

```
if let box = notification.userInfo?["RuleFailNotification"] as? Box<RuleError> {
    let ruleError = box.value
}
```

You can send a Swift enum even with associated values.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `userInfo?["RuleError"]` in the last code block?

Answer (score 0):

**Example. Swift 3**

1: Creating notification name

```
extension NSNotification.Name {
   public static let NetworkReachabilityStatus: NSNotification.Name = 
   NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "NetworkReachabilityStatusChanged")
}
```

2: Some enum

```
enum NetworkReachabilityStatus {
  case connected
  case notConnected
}
```

3: Posting data

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name.NetworkReachabilityStatus,
                  object:nil,
                  userInfo:[kNetworkRechabilityStatus: NetworkReachabilityStatus.notConnected])
```

- kNetworkRechabilityStatus - is string constant

4: Observing

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(networkStatusChanged(_:)), name: Notification.Name.NetworkReachabilityStatus, object: nil)
}

func networkStatusChanged(_ notification: Notification) {
    let status: NetworkReachabilityStatus = notification.userInfo?[kNetworkRechabilityStatus] as! NetworkReachabilityStatus
    switch status {
    case .connected:

        break
    case .notConnected:

        break
    }
}
```

*And don't forget to unsubscribe from notification :)*